# .net core create on memory zipfile

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, zip

I am working on an MVC project where I create dynamically pdf files(wkhtmltopdf) which I want to return in a zip file. The pdf files are generated on fly - I don't need to store them, so my code to return a **single** file is:

```
File(pdfBytes, "application/pdf", "file_name")
```

Taking a look on [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-compress-and-extract-files) their example goes through stored files:

```
 string startPath = @"c:\example\start";
 string zipPath = @"c:\example\result.zip";
 string extractPath = @"c:\example\extract";

 ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath);
 ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath);
```

In my case I want to create N pdf files and return it to the view as a zip..
Something like:

```
ZipFile zip = new ZipFile();
foreach(var html in foundRawHTML)
{
//create pdf

//append pdf to zip
}

return zip;
```

Although this is not doable because:

1. ZipFile and File are statics and cannot be instatiated
2. There is no way to add a file into a zip on fly(in memory)

Any help is welcome

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can use in memory byte arrays and ZipArchive  from System.IO.Compression, there is no need to map the local drive:

```
    public static byte[] GetZipArchive(List<InMemoryFile> files)
        {
            byte[] archiveFile;
            using (var archiveStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var archive = new ZipArchive(archiveStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
                {
                    foreach (var file in files)
                    {
                        var zipArchiveEntry = archive.CreateEntry(file.FileName, CompressionLevel.Fastest);
                        using (var zipStream = zipArchiveEntry.Open())
                            zipStream.Write(file.Content, 0, file.Content.Length);
                    }
                }

                archiveFile = archiveStream.ToArray();
            }

            return archiveFile;
        }

public class InMemoryFile
    {
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public byte[] Content { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Also for anyone tempted to simplify the usings, don't!  If you do it will lead to an invalid zip file.  Use this code as is and you will be fine.